# How do I convert a 0-1 Co ordinates of an image to a format so that i can draw rectangle with the help of OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, annotations

My image shape is (2716, 2088). I got it after fetching my annotation dataset. The co ordinates I am getting are "min":[0.35360904120445646,0.6782253689166354],"max":[0.4603492330334332,0.715828817086451]

I am not able to normalize as multiplying with 255 is not working. And also the opencv function cv2.rectangle is throwing error without integer value.

I want a method to plot the bounding boxes accordingly.

Comment: use multiplication. not with 255. with the width and height of the image.

Comment: It works! i thought as i was taking int values multiplication would change the values drastically. but it is close! thank you